# What happen with missing energy conserved as mass in decay $\rm {}^4H\to {}^3H + n$?

Tags: energy-conservation, nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

What happen with missing energy conserved as mass in decay $\rm {}^4H\to {}^3H + n$?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_hydrogen

$${}^4H \leftrightarrow {}^3H + n$$

$$4.02643 > 3.016049281320 + 1.00866491588$$

$$4.02643 > 4.02471419724$$

$$m > m'$$

$$p = p'$$

Answers point to $E_k$.

This $E_k$ is confirmed or it is only prediction?

I read this report:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0375947403018074

This $E_k$ is not confirmed in any cases.

Comment: Check out [Q value](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_value_(nuclear_science)) for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mass difference appears as kinetic energy
of the decay products ($^3H$ and $n$).
According to the [mass-energy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence)
(the famous $E=mc^2$) the missing mass  ($\Delta m=0.0017$ dalton)
is converted to kinetic energy ($\Delta E=\Delta m\ c^2=1.6$ MeV).
So the process is more correctly written as
$$^4H \to {}^3H + n + \text{ 1.6 MeV}.$$

When we consider only the [invariant masses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass) (also called rest
masses), then the [conservation of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_mass) is obviously violated,
as you already noticed in your question.
But when we, in addition to the invariant masses, also include
the kinetic energy (or more precisely: its equivalent mass),
then the balance is restored.
This is called the [conservation of mass-energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence#Conservation_of_mass_and_energy).

Comment: +1 for using the unfashionable $E=m c^2$. It is precisely the relationship that illuminates what's going on here.

Comment: This Ek is confirmed or it is only prediction? I read this raport:https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0375947403018074

and this Ek is not confirmed in any case.

Comment: @user1785960 The equivalence of $\Delta m$ and $E_k$ has been experimentally confirmed
many times in radioactive decays, with good precision especially in
$\alpha$ deacays, like $^{238}U\to {}^{234}Th+\alpha+\text{4.27 MeV}$

Answer (score 2):

The part of the mass that you lack is converted into energy (mostly kinetic energy aka energy of motion). This is how you see that difference in crowds. We call this phenomenon the [*Mass Defect*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/mass-defect#:%7E:text=Careful%20measurements%20have%20shown%20that,the%20mass%20defect%20(%CE%94m).) $\Delta m$. You can calculate this mass defect and the converted energy by Einstein's famous formula $E = \Delta m \cdot c^{2}$, where $\Delta m$ is the mass difference aka the absolute value of the mass defect and $c$ is the speed of light in vacuum.

This is because what we call mass also includes the mass equivalent of the binding energy of the nucleons in the nucleus. This energy is then converted, causing us to "lose" mass.

In reality, some energy is also "lost" in the form of Thermal Energy. This is known as [*Decay Heat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decay_heat). However, the Decay Heat does not have to be implied directly from the nuclear fission.

You will then also receive the more complete formula that @[Thomas Fritsch](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/153306/thomas-fritsch) already mentioned:
$$
\begin{align*}
\Delta m &= m_{\rm{_{1}^{4}H}} - \left( m_{\rm{_{1}^{3}H}} + m_{\rm{_{0}^{1}n}} \right)\\
\Delta m &\approx 4.02643(11) ~\mathrm{Da} - \left( 3.016049281320(81) ~\mathrm{Da} + 1.00866491595(49) ~\mathrm{Da} \right)\\
\Delta m &\approx 0.00171690272429 ~\mathrm{Da}\\
\\
E &\approx 1.59928476 ~\mathrm{MeV}\\
\\
\rm{_{1}^{4}H} &\overset{\sim}{\to} \rm{_{1}^{3}H} + \rm{_{0}^{1}n} + 1.59928476 ~\mathrm{MeV}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Please either fix the non-rendering MathJax or remove it.

Comment: @Ghoster everything is rendering for me aka i'm not sure what you whant: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPSZC.png

Comment: Interesting. It doesn’t render in Safari on my iPad. I just see the dollar signs with the code inside. But it renders fine in Edge on my PC. Maybe somebody else can figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @Ghoster Safari on iPad has a feature where long strings of digits get converted to telephone-number links. The telephone-number links then break the MathJax conversion. One workaround for posters is to add digit-grouping spaces, e.g. `$3.016\,049\,281\,320(81)$` to produce $3.016\,049\,281\,320(81)$.